# Case study in population biology. Sequences and series, find general solution.

Tags: sequences-and-series, biology

Think about a population of individuals which all have two set of chromosomes (as human do). There is one gene that codes for a helping behaviour. This gene has two alleles (an allele is a variant of a gene. Example: Gene: Eye color, Allele1: blue eyes, Allele2: Braun eyes): Allele `H` (for Helping) and allele `NH` (for non-helping). I am looking for a function that describes the number of alleles of a given type in an population of infinite size at time `t`.

For example: `N(NH, H, t)` is the number of alleles `NH` in a population that was fixed for `H`(meaning that only `H`existed) at time `t`

At time t=-1 the whole population is fixed for allele `H` (N(NH,H,-1) = 0) by definition.
At time t=0, a mutation had occured and one allele in the population is `NH` `N(NH, H, 0) = 1` by definition.
At time t=1, the number of copies of allele NH depends on the fecundity of individuals carrying the mutant allele `NH`.

In order to find the fecundity of the individuals carrying the different alleles we need to understand what these alleles cause. `H`causes their a helping behaviour toward their parents. an individual carrying one or two allele `H` helps its two parents and get a cost `c`in fecundity. The parents of one individual that carries one or two allele `H` have a benefit `b`coming frmo the help they received from one offspring. Therefore the fecundity of someone depends on the number of parents (which is always 2 because nobody ever die in the population (by definition)), the number of offsprings (which vary), the benefit of the behaviour `b`, the cost of the behaviour `c` and their own genotype (allele combination) and the genotype of their offspring which itself. We'll consider that half of the offsprings of a mutant carry the mutant allele. The baseline fecundity (from which we substract `c` or add `b`) is `g`.

summary:

- `b`= benefit
- `c`= cost
- `g`= baseline
- Nobody dies!
- `NH,NH` individuals has no cost `c` (and might have benefits)
- `H,H` and `H,NH` individuals has a cost `c` (and might have benefits)
- the mutant allele is trasnmitted to half the offsprings

We can as well calculate the number of copies of an allele `NH1` in a `NH2`population even if carrying the `NH1` does not make any difference of behaviour than carrying the `NH2`allele

So there are 4 formulas to be found:
$$N(NH1, NH2, t)$$
$$N(NH, H, t)$$
$$N(H, NH, t)$$
$$N(H1, H2, t)$$

I think that:

$$N(NH1, NH2, t) = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{t} \sum_{j=1}^{i} \left(\frac{g}{2}\right)^j$$
Does it seem correct to you?
Step by step:
$$N(NH1, NH2, t=0) = 1$$
$$N(NH1, NH2, t=1) = 1 + g/2$$
$1$ is the first mutant individual. $g/2$ is its number of offsprings divided by 2 because only half the offsprings carry this `NH1` alleles.
$$N(NH1, NH2, t=2) = 1 + g/2 + g/2 + \left(\frac{g}{2}\right)^2 = 1 + g + \left(\frac{g}{2}\right)^2$$
$1$ is the first mutant, $g/2$ the alleles in the offspring created during the previous time step, $g/2$ is the copies produced by the first mutant at this time step, and (\frac{g}{2})^2 is the copies of alleles in the offspring of the offsprings of the first mutant!

The other formulas are harder to find for me. I guess it should looks roughly like the one below but I can't figure out.
$$N(H,NH,t) = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{t} \sum_{j=1}^{i} \left(\frac{g-c+b\cdot((i-j)\cdot(g-c)/2)}{2}\right)^j$$

Step by step:

$$N(H, NH, t=0) = 1$$
$$N(H, NH, t=1) = 1 + \frac{g-c}{2}$$
$$N(H, NH, t=2) = 1 + \frac{g-c}{2} + \frac{g-c + b\cdot\frac{g-c}{2}}{2} + \left(\frac{g-c}{2}\right)^2$$

**What are the 4 formulas?** (one is already found if I haven't made a mistake)

Thanks a lot!

UPDATE: A solution for `N(H,NH,t)` might be found by solving [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497109/looking-for-the-general-solution-of-a-series) question !

Comment: \left( and \right) make appropriate parentheses. It's the difference between $(\frac{a}{b})$ and $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$. Also \cdot is the difference between $a*b$ and $a\cdot b$.

Comment: @alex.jordan Thank you!