# Looking for the General solution of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the general solution (for $f(t)$) of the following series?

$$f(t=-1) = \text{Does-not-apply !}$$
$$f(t=0) = 1$$
$$f(t=1) = 1 + \frac{x-y}{2}$$
$$f(t=2) = 1 + \frac{x-y}{2} + \frac{x-y+b\cdot\frac{x-y}{2}}{2} + \left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2$$
$$f(t=3) = 1 + \frac{x-y}{2} + \frac{x-y+b\cdot\frac{x-y}{2}}{2} + \left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{x-y+b\cdot\left(\frac{x-y}{2}+\frac{x-y+b\cdot\frac{x-y}{2}}{2}\right)}{2} + \frac{ \left(\frac{x-y}{2} + \frac{x-y+b\cdot\frac{x-y}{2}}{2}\right)\cdot \left(x-y+b\cdot \left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2 \right)}{2} + \left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^3$$

This series gets quickly quite complicated. If needed, I might try to write down `f(t=4)`. It is also hard to explain how I generated this series. More information might be found [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496134/case-study-in-population-biology-sequences-and-series-find-general-solution) (replacing `x` by `g` and `y` by `c`, this series is supposed to corresponds to `N(H, NH, t)`).

You can notice that each new step include all the polynomials from the previous step. Always $\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^t$ is added. Also, at each step, is added several polynomials of the kind

$$\frac{ \left(\frac{x-y}{2} + \frac{x-y+b\cdot\frac{x-y}{2}}{2}\right)\cdot \left(x-y+b\cdot \left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2 \right)}{2}$$

where the left parenthesis $\left(\frac{x-y}{2} + \frac{x-y+b\cdot\frac{x-y}{2}}{2}\right)$ and the inside far right parenthesis $\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2$ are changing. These parentheses contain a sum of polynomials that were already seen in the previous steps. For the case of $\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2$ the sum appears only at `f(t=4)`

Thanks a lot for your help!