# Reformulate summations of undefined length

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have the following equation that is not "writable" as its length depends on the variable `t`. So, I'd like to reformulate it.

$N(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{t}\sum_{j=1}^{i}\frac{g-c+b\cdot\left(\sum_{k=1}^{i-j}g-c+b\cdot\left(\sum_{l=1}^{i-j-1}g-c+b\cdot\left(\sum_{l=1}^{i-j-2}g-c+b\cdot\left(\sum_{l=1}^{i-j-3}g-c+b\cdot...\right)\right)\right)\right)}{2}$

This equation should continue up to the point that `i-j-something` equals 1 in which case b should be multiplied by zero!

Hope my question makes sense! To have more information about the origin of this model, one can have a look to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496134/case-study-in-population-biology-sequences-and-series-find-general-solution) post

Thank you

Comment: There are some parantheses missing, I think, otherwise, we have $\sum_{k=1}^{i-j-\ell} g = (i-j-\ell)g$ for every $\ell$.

Comment: Just a general hint: a) parametrized lenghtes of sums occur in the geometric series: $1+q+q^2+q^3+...+q^k $ which can be converted using the generalization to infinite series $(1+q+q^2+q^3+...)- (q^{k+1}+q^{k+2}+...) $ to $$ (q^{k+1}-1)/(q-1) .$$ b) The same idea can be applied if the terms of your sum allow with some function $f(x)$ the expression $f(0) + f(1) + ... + f(k)$ then there is an analogon to the example with the geometric series if you use Bernoulli-polynomials and/or Euler/MacLaurin (See wikipedia for more)

Comment: @martini Indeed I missed some parentheses. I fixed this problem. Thank you

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Thanks for you comment. I can hardly fully understand and solve my problem using your info in point b) and wikipedia. Could you give me a hand?

Comment: @Remi.b: I think it is better first to verify whether your sum indeed can be expressed by the sum of some function $f(k)$ at consecutive arguments - the use of the Euler/MacLaurin-machinery for such a job implies then a lot of stuff to understand beforehand for someone who is not familiar with them...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Well... to me it doesn't look like a sum of functions